# jquery validation and getting errorLabelContainer/wrapper to work with custom validation labels

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, label

I'm using jquery validation and I'm using this:

```
  errorLabelContainer: "#errorList",
  wrapper: "li"
```

to display a list of errors at the top of the page. However, I'm also using this:

```
<label class="error" for="firstName" generated="true"></label>
```

To display individual errors above each field in the form.

The problem is, only one works at a time. If I delete `wrapper: "li"`, the `<label>` shows. If I keep `wrapper: "li"`, the label doesn't show. Any idea what is causing this conflict and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sw87W/39/

Answer (score 1):

> If I delete `wrapper: "li"`, the `<label>` shows. If I keep `wrapper: "li"`, the `label` doesn't show. Any idea what is causing this conflict...

It's not a conflict, it's [how the plugin works](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#wrapper).  The `wrapper` is where you want the message elements to be contained.  By default, it's set to the `window` and the `label` elements are placed next to each form input.  When you change it to `li`, you're telling the plugin to place the message elements inside an `li` in conjunction with `errorLabelContainer`.  **You simply can't use `wrapper` to tell it to be in two places at once**.

> ... and how to fix it?

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, as who would want the same message displayed in two places?

However, if you actually want BOTH a list of errors up top along with an error message next to each element, then you should look at [the `showErrors` function](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors).

You can use the `errorMap` and/or `errorList` objects to construct your list of errors.  And if you use `this.defaultShowErrors()` inside of this function, you will reactivate the default messages that normally appear next to every form input.

However, IMO, you should use the example from the docs, where you keep the default message placement next to every form input, but also have a *single* useful message above the form, i.e.: *"you have 3 error(s), see below"*.

Comment: thanks for your comment. Not my design for the two different sets of error messages, but the design I have to follow. Your explanation is helpful but the solution may be over my head. I'll read about the showErrors function and try to incorporate. Thanks again!